# Cannot drag select on desktop with mouse and drag with finger on touch

Tags: mouse, ubuntu-touch, drag-and-drop

Hello can someone please help me? I have Thinkpad Yoga with touch screen, Ubuntu 23.10 with Ubuntu desktop manager (Wayland)?

When I boot Ubuntu 23.10 from live CD, I can drag select with mouse on desktop. But on my installation, it is not working, most likely because of some custom settings. Does anyone know what settings I need to revert to default as are on Live version?

Second problem is similar. In general, touch - drag - select with finger would be working, but the event is overriden by pop up of context menu. Because the system thinks that I hold my finger on screen for a second, therefore it emulates right-mouse click. It does not consider that I am trying to drag and right-click detection should be disabled. Any help on that please?

Comment: 1. Are desktop icons enabled and are you able to see any icons when you try to add some? 2. Does the dragging work if you do it quickly, like if you start moving your finger fast before touching the screen?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. It seems that some component of Ubuntu desktop manager is missing in my installation and has not been installed with upgrade to 23.10. I have no settings to enable icons on desktop at all, and I noticed that new installation has quite big context menu when I right-click on desktop, while I only have context menu with "Change background..." and "Settngs" options. Any idea why all other menu items are missing?

Comment: I would do `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to make sure. I don't know what menu items are expected, so you could just create another user account.

Comment: I have reinstalled completely ubuntu-desktop. Now I see full context menu and I can drag-select icons with mouse. On touch screen, I could touch and wait to get desktop context menu but it only worked for a while, not working anymore. I can also drag-select with stylus, but is is far from working well. On x-desktop, I could emulate right click with stylus button, but that does not work in wayland. And I cannot configure it with xsetwacom, because that only works in X. Also, in settings in wacom part, I see stylus shown twice and button configuration does not work at all.